# How to do a query in golang, fiber, using database/sql and "github.com/lib/pq" as the postgresql driver

Tags: postgresql, go, go-fiber

This is my controller in fiber

```
func Register(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    user := new(User)

    if err := c.BodyParser(user); err != nil {
        return c.Status(400).JSON(fiber.Map{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
    }

    if user.Username == "" || user.Password == "" {
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusBadRequest).JSON(fiber.Map{
            "error":   "Bad request.",
            "message": "Please include both username and password.",
        })
    }

    query := `SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = $1`

    res, err := db.Query(query, user.Username)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer res.Close()

    return c.JSON("hello")
}
```

But when i hit the endpoint i got

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x865db4]

goroutine 22 [running]:
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, {0xbee8e0, 0xeee440}, 0x1)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1282 +0x54
database/sql.(*DB).query(0x9?, {0xbee8e0, 0xeee440}, {0xb670d2, 0x2d}, {0xc00028fb08, 0x1, 0x1}, 0xc0?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1721 +0x57
database/sql.(*DB).QueryContext.func1(0x0?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1704 +0x4f
database/sql.(*DB).retry(0xc00002c440?, 0xc00028f9f0)
database/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0xc00000ad18?, {0xbee8e0?, 0xeee440?}, {0xb670d2?, 0xc00000ac50?}, {0xc00028fb08?, 0xc0000a3af8?, 0x7cbfaf?})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1703 +0xc5
database/sql.(*DB).Query(...)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1717
example/backend/user.Register(0xc000004600)
        C:/Users/me/Documents/hello/backend/user/user.go:35 +0x1e5
github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2.(*App).next(0xc00000c900, 0xc000004600)
        C:/Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2@v2.48.0/router.go:144 +0x1b2
github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2.(*App).handler(0xc00000c900, 0x81622f?)
        C:/Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2@v2.48.0/router.go:171 +0x78
github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*Server).serveConn(0xc000160000, {0xbeff80?, 0xc00008e0c0})
        C:/Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.48.0/server.go:2363 +0x11d4
github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*workerPool).workerFunc(0xc0000d0140, 0xc000096320)
        C:/Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.48.0/workerpool.go:224 +0xa4
github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*workerPool).getCh.func1()
        C:/Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.48.0/workerpool.go:196 +0x32
created by github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*workerPool).getCh in goroutine 1
        C:/Users/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.48.0/workerpool.go:195 +0x1ab
```

I have another endpoint that is not doing any query and it is working fine, so i don't think there is anything wrong with my connection to the db itself because at this point i'v ealready established a connection to it.

Here is my other endpoint

```
app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusOK).JSON(fiber.Map{
            "status":  "OK.",
            "message": "Service is up and running.",
        })
    })
```

Here is how i connect to postgre, any help would be appreciated

```
package config

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var db *sql.DB

func PostgreInit() error {
    // load env
    if envErr := godotenv.Load(".env"); envErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not load .env")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    var (
        DB_NAME     = os.Getenv("DB_NAME")
        DB_USER     = os.Getenv("DB_USER")
        DB_PASSWORD = os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
        DB_HOST     = os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
        DB_PORT     = os.Getenv("DB_PORT")
    )

    // connect to db
    var err error
    connStr := fmt.Sprintf(
        "postgres://%v:%v@%v:%v/%v?sslmode=disable",
        DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_NAME)

    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Is the db var actually populated? Have you called `PostgreInit`?

Comment: While you do show the function that initializes `db` in package `config`, you do not show how `db` is initialized inside the the `user` package. Note that the two variables are completely separate, initializing a variable inside one package will not automagically initialize a completely separate variable in a separate package.

Comment: i have called the PostgreInit inside my main function like this
`func main() {
 app := fiber.New()
 // db init
 if err := config.PostgreInit(); err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }

 app.Post("/register", user.Register)

 log.Fatal(app.Listen("localhost:8080"))
}`

Comment: Inside my main package main function sorry*

Comment: @poo the variables `config.db` and `user.db` are two separate variables. Initializing one will not initialize the other.

Comment: @mkopriva how do i initialize it once and make it available everywhere?

Comment: @poo to make it available everywhere, the simplest approach would be to export the config's variable and then have any code that needs to use that variable import the config package and then use `config.DB`.

Comment: @mkopriva i have tried doing `var DB *sql.DB` in config then `var db = config.DB` in user but output is still the same, have tried to `fmt.Println(db)` inside of user and it returns `<nil>`

Comment: You should use `config.DB` inside your functions instead of the local `db`. Doing `var db = config.DB` doesn't work because this top-level declaration is executed before the call to `PostgresInit` is executed, therefore `var db = config.DB` just assigns `nil` to the variable `db`.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about that too and now i put `var db = config.DB` inside of the `Register()` func and it is woking, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here in you controller:
**res, err := db.Query(query, user.Username)**
What is **db** ? If db is this; var db *sql.DB, from controller you can not use **db** variable like this because in golang lower case means it is private. That's why it returns invalid memory addresses. You should pass connection with dependency injection or like in function argument or whatever you want.